# How to copy from Google Sheets into a Drawing in another Sheet on macOS Chrome

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome, mac

I'd like to copy an object from one Google Sheet to a Drawing embedded in another Google Sheet. From what I've read, this must be done via the Copy / Paste commands within the Google Sheets web app. However, those commands aren't available in browsers other than Chrome. However, on macOS 10.12.6, and Chrome 62.0.3202.75 they also appear to be unavailable. Even the "Web Clipboard" is disabled.

[image: screencast of paste]

Is there a way to copy an object from one Google Sheet to a Drawing embedded in another Google Sheet on macOS?